# How should I set button's image in same action?

Tags: swift

In my ViewController,

there is multiple buttons connected to the same action

my button is like check or uncheck

I have tried below

My action is triggered, but image didn't change

```
var uncheckBoxImage = UIImage(named: "uncheckBox")
var checkBoxImage = UIImage(named: "checkBox") 

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for button in buttons{
            button?.setImage(uncheckBoxImage, for: .normal) 
            //every button I set uncheckBoxImage first.
        }
    }

@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) { //connect every button
        if sender.imageView == checkBoxImage {
            sender.setImage(uncheckBoxImage, for: .normal)
        }else {
             sender.setImage(checkBoxImage, for: .normal)
        }
}
```

I also tried below, but it can't process multiple button

```
var cube:Bool = false     
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
 cube = !cube
 if cube {
    sender.setImage(checkBoxImage, for: .normal)
        } else {
            sender.setImage(uncheckBoxImage, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

How should I fix these situation ?

Like it has some questions for you

And you just need to click to be check or click again to be uncheck

Comment: that shouldn't even compile, you're comparing UIImageView with UIImage

Comment: set images for button's state for .normal and .selected, and change button's state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the selectedState for buttons.
Set both images for `.normal` and `.selected` state:

```
button?.setImage(uncheckBoxImage, for: .normal)
button?.setImage(checkBoxImage, for: .selected)
```

then, in IBAction:

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For just two states, abstracting "normal" and "selected", it's better to use the above answers, but if you need to handle multiple cases, you can use `<#UIButton#>.currentImage!.isEqual(to: foo)`, to [compare images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) and use only `.normal` state.

This is an example:

```swift
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.currentImage != nil && sender.currentImage!.isEqual(UIImage(named: "a")) {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "b"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "a"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement different button's state, it will change image automatically

```
    var uncheckBoxImage = UIImage(named: "uncheckBox")
var checkBoxImage = UIImage(named: "checkBox")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for button in buttons{
        button?.setImage(uncheckBoxImage, for: .normal)
        button?.setImage(checkBoxImage, for: .selected)
    }
}

@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) { //connect every button
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try with a tintcolor if that works

```
var uncheckBoxImage = UIImage(named: "uncheckBox")
var checkBoxImage = UIImage(named: "checkBox") 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for button in buttons{
        button?.setImage(uncheckBoxImage, for: .normal) 
        button?.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}

@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) { 
     if sender.tintColor == UIColor.clear {
        sender.setImage(checkBoxImage, for: .normal)
        sender.tintColor = UIColor.green
    }else if sender.tintColor == UIColor.green {
        sender.setImage(uncheckBoxImage, for: .normal)
        sender.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple selection then you can use.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     for button in buttons {
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "uncheckBox"), for: .normal)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "checkBox"), for: .selected)
        button.tintColor = .clear
    }
}

@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: UIButton) { 
// toggle automatic changes selection state
            sender.isSelected.toggle()

}
```